# VBA won't load files from stick but will load from computer. Why?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a VBA excel macro that will load .mp3 files and rename them. It works fine when I load the files from a folder on my computer, but I get this error:

```
Runtime error '53':
File not found
```

This is what my code is when it works:

```
fileDir = "C:\MyMusic"
oldFileName = "test.mp3"
newFileName = "test1.mp3"
Name fileDir & "\" & oldFileName As fileDir & "\" & newFileName
```

This is what my code is when it doesn't work (using a flash drive e):

```
fileDir = "E:\"
oldFileName = "test.mp3"
newFileName = "test1.mp3"
Name fileDir & "\" & oldFileName As fileDir & "\" & newFileName
```

I tried to remove the **& "\" &** but it still doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This could be quite a useful question, but IMHO, the question needs to be expanded. Can you view and write files on the stick? What are you using to do that? What are the permissions of the VB program you are running. Can it read and write to the stick?

Comment: Since I'm new to VBA, I didn't know you need permission to read and write to a stick using VBA. How do I find this out?

Comment: Pretty sure this is because you're going through a port, not to an actual drive. The communication is handled differently. You would need to "talk" to the USB drive through the port, not like it's an actual drive.

Comment: @user3063508 You might not need permission, but that was just a thought. How is the stick formatted? It must be ntfs or FAT32, probably FAT32, right. I'd write a test that does I/O to the stick.

Comment: Your two code blocks are not comparable - in the first you have no trailing backslash on `fileDir` and in the second you do: change that, then if it still doesn't work then edit your post to show the modified version.

Comment: Yeah, Like @TimWilliams said... The first one expands to:
 Name "C:\MyMusic\test.mp3" As "C:\MyMusic\Test1.mp3" but the second expands to:
 Name "E:\\Test.mp3" As "E:\\Test1.mp3"

Comment: You should use the `FileSystemObject` to do file operations like this. It will build paths for you so you don't need to manage folder separators and give more informative errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely is rooted in File/Dir permissions. Programmatically Renaming the File (or copying it) to any Folder, which does not resides in "your domain" (i.e., **MyDocuments**, **MyMusic**, etc). requires certain access permission. First, try to perform this operation on any other Dir (e.g. on "C" drive) and see how it works. And, make sure that there is no syntax error in file path (it looks like your 2 statements are different in this regards). Hope this will help,

Answer (score 0):

If you think there might be a folder permissions issue, try editing the filename in Windows Explorer directly. You should be able to tell pretty quick if you have access or not.

Any time I've worked with files programmatically in VBA, I've used the Microsoft Scripting Runtime. In the VBA interface hit the *Tools* menu, *References...*, then check the box next to "[x] Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

You can test programatic the access to that folder by using something like:

```
Dim FSO as Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder as Scripting.Folder
Dim CurFile as Scripting.File
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder("E:\")
For Each CurFile in SourceFolder.Files
    MsgBox CurFile.Name
Next CurFile
```

If you're able to display the filenames using message boxes, you should also be able to change the filename by just assigning it with CurFile.Name = "MyNewName.mp3"